# PIL read and crop takes much longer in same loop

Tags: python, image-processing, python-imaging-library

While trying to optimize my data loader and running some tests, I found that image reading and cropping done in the same loop take much longer but I am not able to understand why?
Here is the test I ran:

```
from PIL import Image
import time
import numpy as np

class CONFIG:
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        self.CROP_DIM = 648

config = CONFIG()

a = time.time()
for _ in range(100):
    hr = Image.open('tests/0801.png')

b = time.time()
for _ in range(100):
    w, h = hr.size
    rand_w = np.random.randint(0, w-config.CROP_DIM)
    rand_h = np.random.randint(0, h-config.CROP_DIM)

    hr.crop((rand_w, rand_h, rand_w+config.CROP_DIM, rand_h+config.CROP_DIM))


c = time.time()
for _ in range(100):
    hr = Image.open('tests/0801.png')

    w, h = hr.size
    rand_w = np.random.randint(0, w-config.CROP_DIM)
    rand_h = np.random.randint(0, h-config.CROP_DIM)

    hr.crop((rand_w, rand_h, rand_w+config.CROP_DIM, rand_h+config.CROP_DIM))

print('%.0f ms' % (1000*(b-a)))
print('%.0f ms' % (1000*(c-b)))
print('%.0f ms' % (1000*(time.time()-c)))
```

This is the output:

```
9 ms
88 ms
7093 ms
```

Can anyone help me in understanding why this is the case?

I am expecting the time taken by the 3rd loop to be an addition of the 1st and 2nd loops.

Comment: `Image.open()` doesn't actually read the file; that only happens when you first do something that requires actual pixel values.  So your first loop performs zero actual loads, the second loop does one, and the third loop does a hundred.

Comment: So reading the pixel values takes much more time as compared to Image.crop, is that right?

Comment: "the pixel values"... that's not how this works. images are compressed. reading an image means decompressing the data.

Answer (score -3):

Well, try to add a `d = time.time()` right after your third loop.
Printing  is pretty slow, and when reaching your third print... well the previous prints mess up the final result.

also, do replace your third print with `print(f"{1000*(d-c):.0f} ms")`

Edit : check your main post comments, jasonharper actually points out the main reasons

Comment: I tried to do that but unfortunately, the output did not change.

Comment: I edited my answer, however you most likely already modified your third print

Comment: Printing is slow, but it doesn’t take 7 seconds.

Comment: Yes, I didn't pay much attention to details when I answered, just spotted one source of delay and pointed it out. In fact the gentleman in the comments of the original post did point out the main reasons.